# How add mppe to Debian kernel 3.2.54-2 x86_64

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, kernel-module

I use debian. 3.2.0-4-amd64 # 1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64 GNU / Linux. I'm trying to setup pptpd, but I'm having trouble adding support "mppe". I' m searching  "kernel-patch-mppe" on the debian site and on google, but without success. I found "mppe" only to "kernel 2.x." I can add mppe in my version? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you no longer need a patch in 3.2 kernels. There's a configuration item CONFIG_PPP_MPPE (EXPERIMENTAL):

```
prompt: PPP MPPE compression (encryption) (EXPERIMENTAL)
type: tristate
depends on: CONFIG_PPP && CONFIG_EXPERIMENTAL
defined in drivers/net/ppp/Kconfig
found in Linux kernels: 3.2–3.8
modules built: ppp_mppe, ppp_mppe
```

Support for the MPPE Encryption protocol, as employed by the Microsoft Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol.